# How do I pause song using from the Album Header button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Hi dear thank you for turning in to my question , I am building a musical app using react-native expo and aws Amplify has my backend tool I am currently having issues I will like to pasue and play the song from my AlbumHeader Component just How I did it in my PlayWidget Component such that when the user hit the big green button in the AlbumHeader Component the song can pause just how I did it in the PlayerWidget Component
button any time I call the `onPlayPress();` from the Album Header Component the song will just start Pausing and Playing Automatically below Are the two component files

AlbumHeader.tsx Component files

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { AppContext } from '../../AppContext';
import { StatusContext } from '../../StatusContext';
import { AlbumContext } from '../../AlbumContext';
import { songFinishContext } from '../../songFinishContext';
import { AlbumHeaderPause } from '../../AlbumPauseContext';
import { playlistContext } from '../../playlistContext';
import { Album } from '../../types';
import styles from './styles';


export type AlbumHeaderProp = {
    album: Album;
}

const AlbumHeader = (props: AlbumHeaderProp) => {

    const { album } = props;

    const { setSongId, songId } = useContext(AppContext);

    var playalbumSong: string[] = new Array();

    const { songStatus } = useContext(StatusContext);
    const { Albumid } = useContext(AlbumContext);
    const { finish, setFinish } = useContext(songFinishContext);
    const { pauseAlbum, setPauseAlbum } = useContext(AlbumHeaderPause);
    const { playlist, setPlaylist } = useContext(playlistContext);

    var Play = 'Play';
    var pause = true;

    if (songStatus == true && album.id == Albumid) {
        Play = 'Pause';
    }

    const playallSong = () => {
       // console.log("George pause Album is" + "" + pauseAlbum);

        const myArray = album.songs.items;
        myArray.forEach((element: any, index: number, array: any) => {
            playalbumSong.push(element.id);
        });

        //get a array of songId and will like to set them in the playerwidget
        setPlaylist(playalbumSong);
        setSongId(playalbumSong[0]);

        // console.log("This the the reform array");

        // console.log(playlist.slice(1));
        // console.log(playlist)

        //if the song finish move to the next 
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={{ uri: album.imageUri }} style={styles.image} />
            <Text style={styles.name}>{album.name}</Text>

            <View style={styles.creatorContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.creator}>By {album.by}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.likes}>{album.numberOfLikes} Likes</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={playallSong}>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText} >
                        {Play}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    )
}

export default AlbumHeader;
```

here is my PlayerWidget.tsx Component

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, Image, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { AntDesign, FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';

import styles from './styles';
import { Song } from "../../types";
import { Sound } from "expo-av/build/Audio/Sound";

import { AppContext } from '../../AppContext';
import { StatusContext } from '../../StatusContext';
import { AlbumContext } from '../../AlbumContext';
import { getSong } from "../../src/graphql/queries";
import { songFinishContext } from '../../songFinishContext';
import { AlbumHeaderPause } from '../../AlbumPauseContext';
import { Album } from '../../types';
import { playlistContext } from '../../playlistContext';

const PlayerWidget = () => {
    //The Sate of the Application
    const [song, setSong] = useState(null);
    const [sound, setSound] = useState<Sound | null>(null);

    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState<boolean>(true);

    const [duration, setDuration] = useState<number | null>(null);
    const [position, setPosition] = useState<number | null>(null);
    //give me the context
    const { songId, setSongId } = useContext(AppContext);
    const { songStatus, setSongStatus } = useContext(StatusContext);
    const { Albumid, setAlbumid } = useContext(AlbumContext);
    const { finish, setFinish } = useContext(songFinishContext);
    const { pauseAlbum, setPauseAlbum } = useContext(AlbumHeaderPause);
    const { playlist } = useContext(playlistContext);



    //update the AlbumHeader if the song keep playing
    const updateAlbumHeader = (isPlaying: any) => {
        // if (isPlaying) {
        //     //console.log('isPlaying');
        //     //console.log(pauseAlbum);
        // } else {
        //     console.log('George the song is not playing');
        // }

        return setSongStatus(isPlaying);
    }

    //Pause the AlbumHeader has to upgrade the State from the AlbumHeader Component
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchSong = async () => {
            try {
                const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getSong, { id: songId }))

                setAlbumid(data.data.getSong.album.id);

                setSong(data.data.getSong);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        fetchSong();
    }, [songId])

    var playlistButton = true;

    const onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (status) => {

        setIsPlaying(status.isPlaying);
        setDuration(status.durationMillis);
        setPosition(status.positionMillis);
        updateAlbumHeader(status.isPlaying);

        if (status.didJustFinish && playlistButton == true) {

            //The logic for playing the next song should be call here
            //  setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate()
            if (playlist.length !== 0) {
                playlist.shift();
                setSongId(playlist[0]);
                console.log(playlist);
                playCurrentSong();
            } else {
                playCurrentSong();
            }
        }
    }

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     if (songId.length !== 0) {
    //         setSongId(songId[0]);
    //     }
    // }, [songId])

    const playCurrentSong = async () => {
        if (song.artist.length > 10) {
            song.artist = song.artist.substring(0, 6) + "...";
        }

        if (song.title.length > 8) {
            song.title = song.title.substring(0, 5) + "...";
        }
        if (sound) {
            await sound.unloadAsync();
        }

        const { sound: newSound } = await Sound.createAsync(
            { uri: song.uri },
            { shouldPlay: isPlaying },
            onPlaybackStatusUpdate
        )

        setSound(newSound)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (song) {
            playCurrentSong();
        }
    }, [song])

    //pause the AlbumHeader Pause
    // const headerpasue = async () => {
    //     if (!sound) {
    //         return
    //     }
    //     if (pauseAlbum) {
    //         await sound.pauseAsync();
    //     } else {
    //         await sound.playAsync();
    //     }
    // }
    //Pause for the Widget

    const onPlayPausePress = async () => {
        if (!sound) {
            return;
        }
        if (isPlaying) {
            
            await sound.pauseAsync();
        } else {
            await sound.playAsync();
        }
    }

    if (pauseAlbum) {
        onPlayPausePress();
        console.log(pauseAlbum);
    }

    const getProgress = () => {
        if (sound === null || duration === null || position === null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return (position / duration) * 100;
    }

    if (!song) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={[styles.progress, { width: `${getProgress()}%` }]} />
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <Image source={{ uri: song.imageUri }} style={styles.image} />
                <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.nameContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>{song.title}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.artist}>{song.artist}</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.iconsContainer}>
                        <AntDesign name="hearto" size={20} color={'white'} />
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPlayPausePress}>
                            <AntDesign name={isPlaying ? 'pausecircleo' : 'playcircleo'} size={25} color={'white'} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    </View>

                </View>

            </View>

        </View>
    )
}

export default PlayerWidget;
```

here is a photo of what I am talking about
[image]

Thank you in advance for trying to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

To pause the song you will need to use the `useEffect()` method provide in react-native with a contex firstly upon called of the playallSong(); have a context that set the song to pause or play like so if the song is playing it will still pause it and  if it is not it will still play it

```
if (songStatus) {
            setPauseAlbum(true);
        } else {
            setPauseAlbum(true);
        }
```

then add the `useEffect()` in your code like this such that when the component mount it called the required function like so

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (pauseAlbum) {
            onPlayPausePress();
            setPauseAlbum(false);
        } else {
            onPlayPausePress();
        }


}, [pauseAlbum])
```